# Is it possible to use topic modeling for a single document

Tags: lda, topic-modeling, topicmodels

Is it rational to use topic modelling for a single document or to be more precise is it mathematically okay to use LDA-gibbs method for a single document.If so what should be value of k and seed.
Also what is be the role of k and seed for single as well as large set of documents.

K and SEED are variable of the function LDA (in r studio).
Also let me know if I am wrong anywhere in this question.

To tell about my project ,I am trying to find out the main topics which can be used to represent the content of a single document.

I have already tried using k=4,7,10.Part of my question also is what value of k should be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the document.  A document could be a 700 page book or a single sentence.  Your k is also going to be dependent on the document I think you mean the number of topics?  If your document is the entire Wikipedia corpus 1500 topics might be appropriate if your document is a list of comments about movies then 20 topics might be appropriate.  Optimizing that number can be done using the elbow method check out [17](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/).

Seed can be pretty random it's just a leaver so your results can be replicated - it runs if you leave it blank.  I would say try it and check your coherence, eyeball your topics and if it looks right then sure you can train an LDA on one document.  A single document should process pretty fast.

Here is an example in python of using seed parameters.  My data set is 1,048,575 rows note the seed is much higher:

```html
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus,
   num_topics=20, alpha =.1, id2word=dictionary, iterations = 1000, 
   random_seed = 569356958)
```

Comment: I need to search for 4 main topics in an article.so I have been using k=4 and seed =1(since I have studied on a website that seed is no. of documents you are giving as input) .Is this a right approach/Am I doing the right thing??

Comment: No seed is not the number of documents.  We use seed when we want to replicate results like if I set the seed to 123 run it then rerun it I should get identical results where as if we don't set a seed your topics will change every time you run the model.